# How to pass path variable by names in web client in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I want to pass path variable using name in web client. I could pass query param by key value pair but how to pass path variable.

For query param, we can do like this by passing key value pair

```
 this.webClient.get()
  .uri(uriBuilder - > uriBuilder
    .path("/products/")
    .queryParam("name", "AndroidPhone")
    .queryParam("color", "black")
    .queryParam("deliveryDate", "13/04/2019")
    .build())
  .retrieve();
```

For path variable, we can do like this by passing value

```
this.webClient.get()
  .uri(uriBuilder - > uriBuilder
    .path("/products/{id}/attributes/{attributeId}")
    .build(2, 13))
  .retrieve();
```

I want like below

```
this.webClient.get()
  .uri(uriBuilder - > uriBuilder
    .path("/products/{id}/attributes/{attributeId}/")
    .pathParam("attributeId", "AIPP-126")
    .pathParam("id", "5254136")
    .build())
  .retrieve();
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to @boobalan's anwser, the simplest way for the case mentioned is:

```
   webClient.get()
    .uri("/products/{id}/attributes/{attributeId}", 2, 13)
    .retrieve();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a **design decision**.

Why such a construct a there for `queryParam` but not for `pathParam`?

In the case of query param, the order in which any query param is present in the uri doesn't matter and the declaration(and assignment of value) of `.queryParam("name", "AndroidPhone")` just once in the `URIBuilder` is enough.

Whereas, in the case of `path param`, the order in which any or different path params appear in the uri matters:

Your suggestion forces declaration of any `pathParam` like `attributeId` in the exact relative position in the URI once and the assignment of the value for that `attributeId` separately, which requires the user to present the correct text `attributeId` input twice in total.

Instead of all this, the `URIBuilder`  has construct only to declare all the `path params` only once while declaring and pass all their values using `.build(..)` in the sequential order.

Comment: Can't you show what you're saying with some code ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @boobalan @puce. I agree with design decision. But my goal is pass path params by name.
I could pass both path/query params once and it works.

```
String url = "http://localhost:8000/{id}/{name}/{id}/{name}?param1={id}&param2={cost}";
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("id", "123");
        params.put("name","Prabhu");
        params.put("cost","35.26");

        WebClient.create().method(HttpMethod.GET)
        .uri(url, params).retrieve();
```

The final url is
http://localhost:8000/123/Prabhu/123/Prabhu?param1=123&param2=35.26